# Refactoring active record global query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some global snippets that are being queried nearly through out the whole application.  All works but when i look at my logs i realise that things don't look pretty. I was wondering if there is a way of refactoring the code. Any help is appreciated.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include GlobalSettings
end
```

The query looks something like this.

```
module GlobalSettings

  def app_facebook_page
    "http://facebook.com/#{account_setting.facebook}" if account_setting.facebook.present?
  end

  def app_linkedin
    "https://www.linkedin.com/#{account_setting.linkedin}" if account_setting.linkedin.present?
  end

  def app_twitter
    "https://twitter.com/#{account_setting.twitter}" if account_setting.twitter.present?
  end

  def app_google_plus
    "https://plus.google.com/#{account_setting.googleplus}" if account_setting.googleplus.present?
  end

  def app_instagram
    "https://instagram.com/#{account_setting.instagram}" if account_setting.instagram.present?
  end

  def app_pinterest
    "https://www.pinterest.com/#{account_setting.pinterest}" if account_setting.pinterest.present?
  end

  def app_address
    account_setting.address.empty? ? '' : account_setting.address
  end

  def app_meta_title
    account_setting.title.empty? ? '' : account_setting.title
  end

  def app_meta_description
    account_setting.description.empty? ? '' : account_setting.description
  end

  def app_city
    account_setting.city.empty? ? '' : account_setting.city
  end

  def app_postcode
    account_setting.postcode.empty? ? '' : account_setting.postcode
  end

  def app_google_analytics
    account_setting.google_analytics.nil? ? '' : account_setting.google_analytics
  end

  def app_country
    account_setting.country.empty? ? '' : account_setting.country
  end

  def app_logo
    if account_setting.logo.blank?
      "#{ current_account.subdomain.capitalize }"
    else
      cl_image_tag("#{ account_setting.logo }", height: '30')
    end
  end

  def app_favicon
    if current_account
      if account_setting.favicon.blank?
        '/assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144.png'
      else
        "#{account_setting.favicon}"
      end
    end
  end

  def app_social_cover
    if current_account
      if  account_setting.social_cover.blank?
        '/assets/facebook-timeline.png'
      else
        "#{account_setting.social_cover}"
      end
    end
  end

  def account_setting
    Setting.last
  end

end
```

My logs look somewhat unclean. What can one do to fix this?

```
Started GET "/settings/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-04 00:44:59 +0200
Processing by SettingsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."subdomain" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["subdomain", "demo"]]
  Setting Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Setting Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings" WHERE "settings"."account_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["account_id", 1]]
  Rendered settings/edit.html.slim within layouts/emet (76.9ms)
  Setting Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.2ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (1.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.3ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "settings".* FROM "settings"  ORDER BY "settings"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT "public"."accounts".* FROM "public"."accounts" WHERE "public"."accounts"."id" IN (1)
  Rendered application/head/_social_metadata.html.slim (146.3ms)
  Rendered application/nav/_navigation_links.html.slim (0.8ms)
  Rendered application/nav/_navigation.html.slim (2.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 479ms (Views: 466.1ms | ActiveRecord: 9.1ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would cache the `account_setting` in the helper. The only method that would be affected would be: `account_setting`. I would write it:

```
def account_setting
  @account_setting ||= Setting.last
end
```

This should result in far fewer round trips to the db.

Comment: Thank you very much. Looks cleaner.